# Synchronizing a physical machine with a virtual machine...is it possible?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I have Ubuntu running in Virtual Box on Windows. I love the possibility to have both OSes running at the same time to quickly switch from one to another. But I would also like to have a physical version of Ubuntu, so I can get full 3D acceleration, access to all my RAM, enjoy my dual screen (maybe possible with VBox, didn't try yet), etc.

I know it's possible to do some physical machine to virtual machine transfer, but is it possible to have a synchronized copy? I would therefore have the possibility to boot on Ubuntu or Windows, and if I choose Windows I can still run Ubuntu from VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu to a physical partition, create a virtual machine but instead of pointing to a virtual disk, point it to boot from the physical partition. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible... you should look into DoubleTake for Linux.

http://www.doubletake.com/ENGLISH/PRODUCTS/LINUX/Pages/default.aspx

I use this product in a Windows environment for synchronization of critical directories.